# Connecting IBM WATSON Conversation to database. To pull the data

Tags: mysql, node.js, watson

I'm pretty new with IBM Watson Conversation. I'm trying to connect IBM Watson Conversation with a database to pull the specific data.

For Example, if a person sends a name of the city or a location, IBM Watson can check the database and if the city name or the location matches. It can pull the data and reply back.

I'm new on StackOverflow, so please don't mind if the question is not clear.

Comment: So what is your expectations or what problem are you facing here

Comment: @yueyou Is it even possible? If yes, can you suggest me some steps or methods? what should I do ? I'm currently using Twilio and nodejs to send and receive the messages.

Comment: Can you ask Watson?

Comment: There is a system entity you can switch on that will give names of cities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to approach this.

1. Watson Conversation has system entities which can detect Locations. It's called [`@sys-location`](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/system-entities.html#sys-location). You will need to switch it on in the system entities section.
2. If your database values are static, you can import them in as normal entities, and look up that way.
3. As @Rohit mentions, you can set your Application layer to handle the issue. You will need to build your own method to detect if Conversation can't capture it. Or you can use something like [NLU](https://www.ibm.com/watson/services/natural-language-understanding/) to capture entities.
4. Watson Conversation now supports [Cloud Functions](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/openwhisk/index.html#getting-started-with-cloud-functions) (FaaS). You can create a cloud function and call it from within Conversation. You would still need a means to capture the entity. Conversation also has a limited time out on cloud functions, so your function has to execute fast or it will be dropped.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Watson Conversation can not access your database directly.You have to access it with your application.